# Calculating Damage Between Two Numbers In Java

Tags: java, random

This is not just about finding a random number,

The answer I am looking for is how to add an expression to a random number to calculate a number based on the expression.

For example a base random number from a range of numbers, 
+ the current lvl of a character, 
* the character's damage gain.

If I am creating a character that does damage between two numbers like this in `java`,

`Damage = 44 to 55 per hit` and I want to write this into a variable, how can I do this?

I am trying this,

```
double BottomDamage = 44 + level * 1.9;
double TopDamage = 55 + level * 1.9;
```

What is the proper way to write something like this if the damage would be between these two numbers `44 through 55 + level * 1.9`???

Comment: Read the duplicate, it will show you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write an interface with a method `damage` and each type of character would have a class that implements this interface.

```
public interface CausesDamage ()
{
    public double damage ();
}

public abstact class CharacterType implements CausesDamage ()
{
   private int _level;
   ...
   public abstract double damage ();
   ...
   public int getLevel ()
   {
       return _level;
   }
}

public class Warrior extends CharacteType ()
{
   public static final int MIN_DAMAGE = ..;
   public static final int MAX_DAMAGE = ..;
   ...
   private Random rand = new Random();
   ...
   public double damage ()
   {
       return rand.nextInt(MAX_DAMAGE-MIN_DAMAGE+1)+MIN_DAMAGE + getLevel()*1.9;
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice.. you beat me to it :)

Comment: Thanks a ton I can use this for each different character. If the 1.9 changes based on the character I am calculating I could just add the 1.9 to a variable in that characters class and just do *Foo there? Would that be the professional way to do that?

Comment: @NichoDiaz It depends on whether this value is constant across all characters of the same type (such as Warrior), or each character can have a different value. The former would imply a constant in the class, while the latter would imply a property in the CharacterType class, with a getter and setter.

Comment: I am missing something still. private rand = new Random() Where are we defining what Random() is?

Comment: @NichoDiaz `java.util.Random` class is part of the Java language. You should import it.

Comment: @NichoDiaz I forgot to declare the type. It should be `private Random rand = new Random()`.

Answer (score 3):

So a random number between the range 44 and 55?

Could be like this:

```
/* returns random number between min (inclusive) and max (inclusive) */
public static int randomInt(int min, int max) { 
    return min + (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)); 
}

int damageRange = randomInt(44, 55);
int damage = damageRange + level * 1.9;
```